# Is this subtitle/slogan grammatically correct? "Documenting my journey to bring Machine Learning and AI to the Web."

Tags: grammar, american-english, slogan

or should it be "Documenting my journey to bring*ing*..."?

Comment: No, it should not but we don't do correcting and editing here per se. And by the way, it is not a sentence.

Comment: It's OK the way it stands, but as Lambie says, it's not a sentence.  It's a phrase that would make an excellent subtitle.  I Robot: Documenting my Journey to Bring Machine Learning and AI to the Web

Comment: @JMR It is a blog subtitle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both are terrible.

It would be less bad if you wrote:

“**How** I brought …”

Why? Because you can replace phrases of several words with contorted and unnatural verb forms by a one single-syllable English word that anybody can understand.

However I fear for the web.

Comment: It's not really a sentence. It's a blog subtitle/slogan.

Comment: "To bringing" is not English, so you must be a learner. In this case I would suggest you try to perfect clear simple English, which is no less educated or literary for being so. For example, the title of Robert Browning's poem was not "The manner of our transmission of the felicitous intelligence along the Ghent-Aix transport network", but "How we brought the good news from Ghent to Aix". Think about that.